# Using Futures in Scala?

Tags: scala, future

I am trying to incorporate a database into my http-microservice.

The microservice has a function `getValueFromInternet(val: Foo): Future[Value]` which was being called by my microservice on a `GET` request. Now, I want it to happen such that, a function `getValue(val: Foo): Future[Value]` would first query a db and if the database returns no results, call `getValueFromInternet`. The database query returns a `Future[Seq[Value2]]` where I can convert Value2 to Value using a function. And if no entry is found corresponding to that value, an empty `Vector` is returned.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
def getValue(val: Foo): Future[Value] = {
  val resultFuture = db.getValue(val)
  // 1st attempt. Clearly wrong
  resultFuture onComplete {
    case Success(Vector()) => getValueFromInternet(val)
    case Success(vec) => convertValue2to1(vec.head)
  }
  // 2nd attempt. This is also wrong
  resultFuture match {
    case Future(Success(Vector())) => getValueFromInternet(val)
    case Future(Success(vec)) => convertValue2to1(vec.head)
  }
}
```

I would be grateful for any help suggesting how I can do this.
I have implemented the database and microservice independently and you can find them [here](https://github.com/yashsriv/akka-movie-microservice) and [here](https://github.com/yashsriv/sqlite-slick)

Comment: Please include a [minimal self-contained](http://sscce.org/) description of the problem. Something we can compile using only the code given in the question itself is much more likely to get an answer and to be useful to others.

Comment: about futures in scala 2.12, check out this https://github.com/viktorklang/blog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `flatMap`, since the thing you want to do if the first operation does not return a result also returns a future.

This is as close to your code as possible while still compiling. Note that you can't have identifiers called `val` in scala, since that is a keyword.

```
def getValue(v: Foo)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Value] = {
  val resultFuture: Future[Seq[Value2]] = db.getValue(v)
  resultFuture.flatMap { vec =>
    if(vec.isEmpty)
      getValueFromInternet(v)
    else
      Future.successful(convertValue2to1(vec.head))
  }
}
```

Comment: You actually can, just with backticks ;) `val`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you think this is possible using recoverWith ?? because this seems just like what recoverWith was made to do

Comment: @Łukasz, yes I know. I still wouldn't recommend it. @Yash Srivastav, No. recoverWith is for recovering a failed future. However, an empty vector is a successful result from the DB, not a failure. You would need `recoverWith` to also deal with real DB failures (get value from internet if db is unavailable).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that either, but still, it is possible.